# Perl: Using Log4Perl with log4j.xml

Tags: perl

Can anyone point me to a place where I can find working examples of using Log4Perl with log4j.xml. I read that DOMConfigurator can be used for this purpose but I couldnt find how to use it. I dont have an option to use log4j.properties as we use a internal framework that uses log4j.xml.

Sorry for my basic question.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to test this so I can't say it will work but from what I read in docs and source it looks like this should work:

```
use Log::Log4perl::Config::DOMConfigurator;
my $dom_conf = Log::Log4perl::Config::DOMConfigurator->new(file => 'log4j.xml');
my $conf = $dom_conf->parse();
```

I think `$conf` will be a hash ref with all your options in it and I think you can use that to init Log::Log4perl or just query values.